# Unit testing a Scalatra POST service with specs2

Tags: unit-testing, scala, scalatra, specs2

I am trying to use this test to test my webservice:

```
  "POST /phaseupdate" should {
    "return status 200" in {
      put("/phaseupdate", Map("filename" -> "test1", "entryaddress" -> "address 1","name" -> "starting","percentcomplete" -> "10")) {
        status must_== 200
      }
    }
  }
```

And the webservice definition is:

```
  post("/phaseupdate/:filename/:entryaddress/:name/:percentcomplete") {
```

But I am getting a 404 error, so it appears the way I am passing the parameters is wrong.

What is the correct way to get this test to call my webservice?

**UPDATE**

So this works, so my definition of the service is not what I expected:

```
put("/phaseupdate/test1/address1/starting/10") {
```

Comment: Is your webservice realy running at the moment you test?

Comment: @T.Grottker - Yes, it is started up by the framework, and I have several other tests that succeed, testing other webservices.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the webservice with this url?

Comment: @T.Grottker - The error I get is that it can't find the endpoint, so it seems that in order to call this I will need to use a different approach to call my service.

Comment: @T.Grottker - It appears the way I am defining my webservice, with scalatra is wrong, I will update how I got it to work, and ask a new question.